# Divide $20$ into $2$ parts such that the product of square of one part and the cube of other is maximum. Then, the two parts are :

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

The idea would be to suppose 2 variables $x$ and $y$ such that $x+y=20$. And let $f(x,y)=x^2y^3$(assuming $y>x$). Now convert the 2 variable function, i.e. $f(x,y)$ to a single variable function, i.e. $g(x)$ by substituting $y=20-x$  in $x^2y^3$.

Then, you proceed to find $g '(x)$ and set it to zero to obtain critical values for maximum and minimum.

Here, $g(x)=x^2(20-x)^3$ and  $g '(x)= 2x(20−x)^3-3x^2(20−x)^2$.

Now, $g '(x)= 2x(20−x)^3-3x^2(20−x)^2$= $0$, which implies $x=0$ and $x=20$

Since $20$ is split into $2$ parts and $x^2y^3$ is maximum, so $x≠20$ or $ x≠0$
as the product wouldn't be maximum in that case and will equal $0$.

So, I am not able to obtain a critical value for $x$. Do I need to simplify $g '(x)$ further and then equate it to zero to obtain critical values? Would further simplification be of any significance?

Ultimately, How do I proceed further to find $x$ and $y$?

Note: I am also open to other kinds of solutions that don't involve calculus. Looking forward to other methods for answering this question?

Comment: How do you know $g'(x)=0$ only yields $x=0$, $x=20$?  Seems like it can be factored further

Comment: You've missed a minus sign when you applied the product rule.

Comment: To find maximum or minimum, you find the first derivative and set it equal to zero to find critical values and then check the sign of the first derivative on either side or in between of the critical values to obtain maximum or minimum or neither.

Comment: You did in fact miss a solution to $g'(x)=0$, but it doesn't matter because your $g'$ is wrong anyway.

Comment: Ohh yes, I mistyped the g '(x). I have edited it but the critical values will still come out to be $x=20$ and $x=0$ when $g '(x)=0$. I haven't simplified the g '(x) further and have just intuitively checked that for $x=0$ or $x=20$, g '(x) will come out to be $0$.

Comment: As @Randall stated, you should factor $g'(x)$ to get all solutions to $g'(x)=0$. $$g'(x)=5x(8-x)(20-x)^2$$ So critical points are at $x=0,8,20$.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. Taking common terms would indeed simplify the result. Thank you!

Comment: Are there other ways to answer this question?

Comment: factor out the two known solutions of g' than you solve the rest for max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were correct with $$ g′(x)= 2x(20−x)^3−3x^2(20−x)^2 = 0 $$
but $ 0 $ and $ 20 $ aren't the only solutions.
$$ 2x(20−x)^3−3x^2(20−x)^2 = x(20-x)^2(2(20-x) - 3x) = 0 $$
which gives you three solutions.
$x = 0$, $(20-x)^2 = 0,$ with $x = 20 $ and $2(20-x) - 3x = 0$, the simplification of which gives us $40 - 2x - 3x = 0$ leading us to x = 8.
$$ $$ So the answer is x = 8, y = 12.